# Qt android one activity?

Tags: android, qt, android-activity

I am working on a android app using Qt and I have found that the amount of RAM consumed by the app keeps growing as we add new features (code) on the project.
From what I have been reading on the android documentation I found that an android app is split into different activities and activities not in the foreground may be cleaned by the system .

Since Qt android apps live in one activity ,all my code lives in one activity and my RAM consuption is growing to unacceptable levels.Is there a way I can split my app into different activities ?Or should I try to pinpoint my problems somewhere else?

I am fairly new to the android world and I might be trying to find the problem in a wrong place.Any input will help.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working on the JNI side, automatic cleanup by the garbage collector is gone (as far as I understand).  You can delete and clean up manually as necessary as you would with any C++ project.

Here are some more or less generic thoughts on Qt + memory management.

Qt uses smart pointers behind the scenes for a lot of different kinds of elements, like strings, and lists and more.  So you just let those objects go out of scope and they are taken care of.  But for widgets and other large structures you are putting on the heap, make sure they are getting deleted when you are done with them.

Also look at any loops or repeated code and make sure you aren't allocating more stuff onto the heap with every loop.  Or in other words, count up all your non QObject/QWidget `new` calls and make sure that there is a matching `delete` call.

For `QObject` and `QWidget`, make sure the parenting is correct.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

Also QWidgets have an attribute for delete when close.  Modal dialogs often should be left on the stack.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum

```
Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I m going to run my program through valgrind and see what it reports.I hear it can help pin point memory errors and leaks.